# SQL query on nested select (maybe?)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

My simplified schema is as follows:

```
Table1(id, age, name)
Table2(id1, id2)
```

I need to compare the age between the IDs in Table2 and return the name of ID1 if ID1 is older than ID2.

I am able to get the age of ID1 and compared it to an arbitrary age, say 20:

```
SELECT name from (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
                 on Table1.id1 = Table2.id1 
                 where age > 20);
```

But how should I get the age of ID2 to replace the "20" there? Thanks in advance

My simplified schema is as follows:

```
Table1(id, age, name)
Table2(id1, id2)
```

I need to compare the age between the IDs in Table2 and return the name of ID1 if ID1 is older than ID2.

I am able to get the age of ID1 and compared it to an arbitrary age, say 20:

```
SELECT name from (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
                 on Table1.id1 = Table2.id1 
                 where age > 20);
```

But how should I get the age of ID2 to replace the "20" there? Thanks in advance

=====
EDITED: I only need to print out the name when Id1 is older than Id2. That being said, the name has to be distinct as well. Say:

```
Table1: (1, 10, "name1")
        (2, 20, "name2")
        (3, 30, "name3")

Table2: (2, 1)
        (2, 3)
        (3, 1)
        (3, 2)
```

The result will be "name2" "name3" as in the first comparison, 2 is older than 3; 2nd comparison as 2 is younger than 3 I don't need to print it; 3rd comparison, 3 older than 1, print 3; fourth comparison, although 3 is older than 2, it has been printed before so you don't have to print it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, then you just need to `join` to `table1` multiple times and then you can compare their ages using a `case` statement:

```
select 
  case when t1a.age > t1b.age then t1a.name else t1b.name end older
from table2 t2
  join table1 t1a on t2.id1 = t1a.id
  join table1 t1b on t2.id2 = t1b.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/644de/3)

---

Based on your edits, just add `where` criteria with `distinct`:

```
select distinct t1a.name
from table2 t2
  join table1 t1a on t2.id1 = t1a.id
  join table1 t1b on t2.id2 = t1b.id
where t1a.age > t1b.age
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eca9ff/1)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply.  I have added some more explanations to my question. Basically I only need to print out the name of ID1 (never ID2) when it is older than ID2 and it should only be printed out once as long as there exists a comparison when ID1 is older than ID2.

Comment: @user3669481 -- take a look at the edits, hopefully I've better understood.